# Get the width of multiple pictures stored in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hei guys, im facking an issue getting the width of multiple pictures stored in DOM.

**My html looks like:**

```
<div id="showcase" class="showcase">

        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content"> 
                <img src="https://asp.zone-secure.net/v2/90/10158/58365/multimedia/1_1/1.jpg" alt="02" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="showcase-slide">
            <div class="showcase-content">
                <img src="https://asp.zone-secure.net/v2/90/10158/58365/multimedia/1_1/2.jpg" alt="02" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="showcase-slide">
             <div class="showcase-content">
                <img src="https://asp.zone-secure.net/v2/90/10158/58365/multimedia/1_1/3.jpg" alt="02" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="showcase-slide">
         <div class="showcase-content">
                <img src="https://asp.zone-secure.net/v2/90/10158/58365/multimedia/1_1/4.jpg" alt="02" />
            </div>

        </div>
```

**What i have tried:**

```
for(var i=0; i < mineContor; i++){
                    var img = $("img")[i];
                    console.log(img.width); 
                }
```

Specification: mineContor = 4 (how many imgs i have);

**Issue:**

```
240
(3) 0
```

Sometimes is like the console above, where 240 px width is the real width of 1st picture.
Sometimes like bellow.

```
(4) 0
```

Even if `console.log(img.src);` returns the 4 images that i have in DOM with the correct src path! Also, these images has different dimensions.

**Question:**

Why the 0 and not the width?

Comment: I think that's because the images aren't fully loaded!

Comment: What is the value of `mineContor`?

Comment: Check again the brief please, i wrote there. But ill say here once again, the value of variable mineContor is 4 (number of images available in DOM).

Comment: @AbraarArique As you should know, the parameter i<4 if i=0 run 4 times only coz its  >4 not >=4 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your code in `$(window).load(function(){});`

This is because it executes when all other things are loaded as well, such as the images.

So your code becomes:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   for(var i=0; i < mineContor; i++){
                    var img = $("img")[i];
                    console.log(img.width); 
                }
});
```

Comment: You're right, as many other guys that answered the question... Images wasnt fully loaded :( I'm gonna accept the answer cuz its first in 8 minutes.

Comment: I used to store the values in array, and it looks like 240,240,240,540 which is correct, but these values are in same array which changes its value on position 0. So the array is populated only on position 0, and 1,2,3 are empty if i list in that for for the array[i]

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").each(function(){

console.log($(this).css("width"));

   OR

console.log($(this).width());
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dxo2mbya/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea with your variable `mineContor`. It doesn't seem to be a very flexible solution.
I would suggest an alternative solution without using jQuery or any external library:

```
// get all images (img) on the page
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
// iterate over the images and return the width for every single image
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    console.log((i + 1) + '. image has width ' + images[i].width + 'px');
}
```

That works better and is more flexible than hard coding the number of images in a variable.

EDIT:

The above code was initially meant just as a supplement to the other answers as an alternative without jQuery and avoiding hard coding the variable `mineContor`.

The images in the document can be readen only after the DOM has been fully loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Here comes an extension showing how to implement the code example on the page:

```
var getImageWidth = function() {
    // declare all variables in the beginning
    var images, i;
    // get all images, it returns an HTMLCollection, an array-like object
    images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    // iterate over the images and get the width for every one of them
    console.log((i + 1) + '. image has width ' + images[i].width + 'px');
}

// execute the function after the page has finished loading
// important: no brackets after the function
window.onload = getImageWidth;
```

Adapt the body of the function according to your needs either by rearranging the output with `console.log` or by returning the values, possibly as an array.

Comment: I'd like to add the code for another gallery img, so i need to know dinamically how many imgs i've got!

Comment: I just saw "images.length" which returns the value of mineContor. You're right, its a nice solution. Thank you!

Comment: @OzZie Exactly that's the point. You can reuse the code without knowing in advance how many images there are on the page.The first line of code in the example returns an array-like object (HTMLCollection) of elements. As such it has the property `length` - the value you manually declared.

Comment: As the boys said, even your code must be adeed in a onload function so... even if i declare the array i use to add whole images width as a global when i call the length of it (of the array with width) it sais its 0 ... why so?

Comment: @OzZie Sorry for not explicitly mentioning that. This code must be called after the DOM has fully loaded. It can't change anything about that. I'll edit my answer to cover this issue.

Comment: What about the second answer... i cant pass a value which is arrayofwidth.length where arrayofwidth is the array intializaed with width values from onload function to another function... The array was declared as global and it shows 0 (length) on another function but 4 on the onload function. Where i am wrong?

Comment: @OzZie I dont' know to which answer do you refer and to which function do you want to pass the value. Avoid global variables if possible. If you return an array containing the width of every image, it'll have the same length property as `var images`. You can then pass the return value of the above function (getImageWidth) to another function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83441/discussion-between-ozzie-and-cezar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Write your code inside `$(function()` which will ensure that all DOM structure is ready. Then iterate all images and call `.width()` method which will give you the width of each image.

```
$(function(){
  $('#showcase .showcase-content img').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).width());
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hz6zvvth/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

That is because only `$("img")[0]` returns the DOM object of the first occurring image element, with the width property. `$("img")[1]` and etc will not. The `[n]` does not return the next occurring image, which I believe is what you thought. Also, if you want to loop through each image, why not use the `$.each()` method in jQuery?

```
$('#showcase img').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work better?

```
$.each($('img'), function(index, value){
   console.log($(value).width()); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hz6zvvth/